# why does this code keeps on showing error

Tags: java, methods, constructor, instance-variables

```java
public class Store {

    //instance fields 
    String productType;
    int inventoryCount;
    double inventoryPrice; 

    //constructor method
    public Store(String product,int count,double price) {
        productType = product;
        inventoryCount = count;
        inventoryPrice = price;
    }

    //main method 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Store cookieShop = new Store("cookies",12,3.75);
        System.out.println("my cookie shop menu  " + cookieShop.product);
    }
}
```

reason why this error is constantly showing?

```
Store.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println("my cookie shop menu  " + cookieShop.product);
                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable product
  location: variable cookieShop of type Store
1 error
```

Answer (score 1):

The field in the class is named `productType`, you are referencing it by its name in the constructor signature. So use:

```
    Store cookieShop = new Store("cookies", 12, 3.75);
    System.out.println("my cookie shop menu  " + cookieShop.productType);
```